# How many types of typeface should I use to make the better user experience?

Tags: usability, user-centered-design, font, style-guide

I am designing a style guide for my project and read few articles that suggest it's a good practice to combine more than one style of typefaces to enhance user experience. May I ask how to decide the typefaces and how many typefaces should I use in my web interface? My main focus is to improve usability for very technical users who will access the website, but at the same time, I would like to take care of the look and feel of my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typography on the web is a vast field which requires a deep understanding before you can make the right choices. There are two canonical resources on the web that are available for free:

- [Butterick's Practical Typography](https://practicaltypography.com/)
- [The Elements of Typographic Style Applied to the Web](http://webtypography.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You should read this article on UXplanet, it gives some good insight.

https://uxplanet.org/10-tips-on-typography-in-web-design-13a378f4aa0d